# Set Background to an Image for Save to gallery

Tags: react-native, qr-code, react-native-svg, react-native-fs

I have a qr-code in my react-native project from `react-native-qrcode-svg` like this:

```js
<QRCode
  value={singleTicketResponse.voucher}
  size={width * 0.5}
  getRef={(c) => (svg = c)}
/>;
```

I want to save this QR to the gallery! I use this code for saving it to gallery!

```js
svg.toDataURL((data) => {
  RNFS.writeFile(
    RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath + `/${tracking_code}.png`,
    data,
    "base64"
  )
    .then((success) => {
      return CameraRoll.save(
        RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath + `/${tracking_code}.png`,
        "photo"
      );
    })
    .then(() => {
      onClose();
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("saveToGallery", e);
    });
});
```

Now I want to save this QR with white background in the gallery!

Because now, I save QR to gallery and gallery show this in black background and scanner does not detect QR-code!!! **Is there any solution??**

In other words, how to combine two images (white background and QR-code) or how to set a background for this image??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `quietZone` props to `QRCode` component. This props is the margin around the QR-code and when yo save the QR it is shown!!

```
<QRCode
  value={singleTicketResponse.voucher}
  size={width * 0.5}
  quietZone={10} // this props
  getRef={c => (svg = c)}
/>
```